# How to load data from Firebase in label?

Tags: swift, firebase, label

The problem is that the label doesn't change its text with the text from Firebase in the "Nick" child.

This is how my code looks like:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
refHandle = ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    print(dataDict)
})

let userID: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
ref.child("Users").child(userID).child("Nick").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
    snapshot in 
    print(snapshot)
    let m = snapshot.value as? String
    self.label.text = m
})
```

And this is how my Firebase data looks like:

[image]

Comment: do you want (nick) or (mxm) ?

Comment: i want (mxm) in label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userID)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
               if let result = snap["Nick"] as? String {
                  self.label.text = result
               }else
                  print("nick not exist")
               }
            }else{
               print("maybe USER UID not exist in database ")
            }
         })
```

Comment: now it always prints: "maybe USER UID not exist in database" :/

Comment: you can use **ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in  if snapshot.hasChild("Nick") {
                print("exist")
            }})** just to make sure if nick is exist or not

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using `observeSingleEvent` method from Firebase Library, use `observe` method instead:

```
ref.child("Users").child(userID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if let snapshotDict = snapshot as? [String:Any] {
        if let nick = snapshotDic["Nick"] as? String {
            self.label.text = m
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: @МаксимПереход I just corrected my answer. Try removing `of` from the method `observe(.value, with:.....`

Comment: hm, now label changing his text on void(

Comment: What do you mean by "changing his text on void"?

Comment: default text in my label is "label", so when my program launching, label changing text on " "

Comment: I edited my answer once again now trying to get the entire dictionary of values from the user. You should also check if the UserID is correct.

Comment: the text does not change again. Maybe problem in Firebase?